# Check if a polygon intersects other polygons within each cluster

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with these two columns - cluster_num and Polygons. Cluster_num is an integer type nullable type field and Polygons is a Geography type repeated field like so :

| cluster_num | Polygons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | polygon1.1 |
|  | polygon1.2 |
| 2 | polygon2.1 |
|  | polygon2.2 |
|  | polygon2.3 |

NOTE: For the sake of brevity, I have abbreviated each polygon here.

I need to go inside each "cluster_num" individually and check if there are any intersecting pairs of polygons. Cluster_num had been generated by running a DBSCAN clustering over the entire dataset of Polygons.

The issue is that I need to check for the intersection between each distinct pair of polygons for each distinct cluster_num. As an example, in a hypothetical cluster_num = 4 row having 5 polygons, there can be 10 distinct pairs of polygons and I need to check for intersection in each pair.

The first step to solve this would be generating these distinct pairs for EACH individual cluster_num and I am stumped at this. The second step would be to just use st_intersects for each pair of the generated pairs and check for the intersection. However, I am not able to figure out an SQL query (or a succession of queries) to solve the first step.

**Edit**: Desired output after the first step:

| cluster_num | Polygons | Polygons_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | polygon1.1 | polygon1.2 |
| 2 | polygon2.1 | polygon2.2 |
|  | polygon2.1 | polygon2.3 |
|  | polygon2.2 | polygon2.3 |

Note that we have all **DISTINCT** combinations of polygons for **EACH** individual cluster_num.

I have looked into `cross join` to generate a cartesian product, however, this will give me repeated pairs and also I am not sure how to do a `cross join` for each cluster_num individually.

Comment: please provide example of output of that first step

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Added the example output of the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The first step to solve this would be generating these distinct pairs for EACH individual cluster_num**. The second step would be to just use st_intersects for each pair of the generated pairs and check for the intersection. However, **I am not able to figure out an SQL query (or a succession of queries) to solve the first step**.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with temp as (
  select cluster_num, Polygon, 
    row_number() over(partition by cluster_num) id 
  from `project.dataset.table` t, t.Polygons as Polygon
)
select cluster_num, 
  array_agg(struct(t1.Polygon as Polygon1, t2.Polygon as Polygon2)) pairs
from temp t1
join temp t2
using(cluster_num)
where t1.id < t2.id
group by cluster_num
```

if to apply to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 cluster_num, ['polygon1.1', 'polygon1.2'] Polygons union all
  select 2, ['polygon2.1', 'polygon2.2', 'polygon2.3']
)
```

output is

[image]

> From OP's comments - I am getting the error "Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit." I think it might be because some of the Polygons are quite large

Just remove grouping as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with temp as (
  select cluster_num, Polygon, 
    row_number() over(partition by cluster_num) id 
  from `project.dataset.table` t, t.Polygons as Polygon
)
select cluster_num, 
  t1.Polygon as Polygon1, 
  t2.Polygon as Polygon2
from temp t1
join temp t2
using(cluster_num)
where t1.id < t2.id
```

with output

[image]

so now - all pairs are in their own rows so shouldn't cause a size issue

Comment: I tried this on my dataset and am getting the error ''Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit." I think it might be because some of the Polygons are quite large. 
Also, I see that you have used `partition by` in your query, which has a limit of 4000, if I have more than 4000 clusters, it would not work.

Comment: Great, removing the grouping made it run! Thank you.

Comment: sure. consider also voting up the answer :o)